# Are there solvers for the Word Problem for finitely presented groups?

Tags: math-software

I know the Word Problem for finitely presented groups is undecidable in general.

I am looking for software that takes a FPG and a word as input and *tries* to figure out (using some heuristics) whether it is equal to the neutral element.

Comment: You could try to run the Knuth-Bendix procedure for a while and reduce with the partial rewriting sytsem obtained.